# Entered values from scanf always return 0.0000

Tags: c

After entering any values of `p`,`n`,`r`; the value of `i` is only returning 0.0000.

```c
int main()
{
    int p,n;
    float r,i;

    i=p*n*r/100;

    printf("enter principle=\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    printf("enter rate=\n");
    scanf("%f",&r);

    printf("enter no.of years=\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("value of i=%f",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should calculate the value of `i` after inputing `p`, `n`, `r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `p, n, r` are not initialized at the line `i=p*n*r/100;`. You have to do the calculation *after* reading the values.

```
int p,n;
float r,i;
printf("enter principle=\n");
scanf("%d",&p);
printf("enter rate=\n");
scanf("%f",&r);
printf("enter no.of years=\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
i=p*n*r/100; /* do calculation after reading values */
printf("value of i=%f",i);
```